# What is the naming convention used when mapping a pdf template within nested repeat fields?

Tags: pdf, orbeon

According to the instructions on: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/user-guide/form-builder-user-guide/pdf-generation#TOC-Multi-line-text

It states to map fields from orbeon forms to pdf templates (my-section$my-field). This works perfectly. When using repeats we researched on how this naming convention changes slightly to include a "$1"... (ie: my-section$my-field$1, my-section$my-field$2).

We have a form that has a nested repeat and have tried to apply the same naming convention and it has not worked. We have also experimented with other combinations to no success.

Please let us know how to map fields from nested repeats to pdf templates.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you mention, using `$1`, `$2`… at the end of the field id, looks correct to me. You can see this used in the DMV 14 example; you'll find it linked from the examples home page, and you can look at the [source for that example on GitHub](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/tree/master/src/resources/forms/orbeon/dmv-14/form). If you open the PDF with Acrobat, you can see the ids, which follow the syntax you mentioned:

[image: DMV 14 repeat]

Comment: our form is working in this way as well. We are having issues when we have nested repeats (a repeat within a repeat).

Comment: @landyg, I see: nested repeats are not supported right now by the code that fills out a PDF template. I imagine that Orbeon Forms could support a syntax like `vehicle$driver$3-2` for to identify the second driver of the third vehicle. There is a similar syntax being used between the server and the browser, but it can't be used right now in a PDF. I added an RFE for this: http://goo.gl/AVw52.

Comment: do you know timeline/normal turnaround for the rfe

Comment: @landyg, unfortunately, we don't have plans to implement this right now. So most likely this won't get implemented soon, unless a client with a Development Support plan sponsors this feature.